# How to make such functioning screen like this in flutter?

Tags: flutter

[image]

In this image, which is from figma. There is keypad on screen, which, when entered shows up in that square box. How do I make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, Catch the idea and apply into your design.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

   MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String enteredText = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Column(
          children: [

            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Text('Welcome U_Identity_Code'),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Wrap(
              direction: Axis.horizontal,
              spacing: 20,
              children: [
                getBox(enteredText.length >= 1? Colors.black : Colors.grey),
                getBox(enteredText.length >= 2? Colors.black : Colors.grey),
                getBox(enteredText.length >= 3? Colors.black : Colors.grey),
                getBox(enteredText.length >= 4? Colors.black : Colors.grey),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Expanded(child: GridView.builder(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 3,
                crossAxisSpacing: 20,
                mainAxisSpacing: 20,
              ),
              itemCount: 10,
              itemBuilder: (context,index){
                return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: (){
                    setState(() {
                      enteredText = enteredText + index.toString();
                    });
                  },
                  child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                        border: Border.all(width: 1 , color: Colors.black),

                      ),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(index.toString()),
                      )
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),),

            Text('EnteredText: $enteredText'),
            SizedBox(height: 20,),
          ],
        )
    );
  }

  Widget getBox(Color color){
    return Container(
      width: 10,
      height: 10,
      color: color ,
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Hope it helps you.